# Regular expressions: .* versus (.*) and Character Classes best practices

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a quick question regarding regular expressions. Is there
a difference between .* and (.*) in pattern matching? The grouping
seems redundant. I ask this question because I see both forms
being used in Apache's RewriteCond or RewriteRule expressions.

Additionally I would like to know whether it is considered to
be a good practice to group character classes when matching
patterns, e.g. ab\scd versus ab(\s)cd. Here the latter seems
more intuitive.

Comment: `(.*)` forms a group around whatever was matched by `.*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*)` creates a group, which can be re-matched or substituted in later as `\1` or similar. (The number is the number of the group, from left to right.) The `()` is what makes it a group, so `.*` will match the same, but isn't a group.

Matching groups uses more memory, and takes longer, so it should be avoided unless the groups are necessary.

You can make groups work faster with less memory if you don't need to remember the contents. Just add `?:` after the first parenthesis, e.g. `(?:this)` instead of `(this)`.

Here are some examples of necessary grouping:

- `(.*),(.*)` pattern with substitution of `\1\t\2`, which replaces a coma-separated pair with a tab-separated one. You need groups to make the substitution.
- `(abc)*`, which matches any number of `abc`s in a row, e.g. `abcabcabcabc`. The group is required to tell that it's *all* of `abc` that's repeating, not just the `c`. (Note that this is more efficient as `(?:abc)*`.)

As for character classes, there is no reason to make a group out of character classes. `ab(\s)cd` will match like `ab\scd`, but the former is much slower and uses more memory. If you want additional clarity for human readers, surrounding the character class with square brackets (that are usually used to define a custom character class) can usually be done for no or minimal additional cost. E.g. `ab[\s]cd`. (Thanks to Hobbs for suggesting this.)

Comment: Most regex dialects allow backslash character classes inside bracketed character classes, so you can use `[\s]` for readability at (probably) no cost.

Comment: @hobbs That's true. The only additional cost is at compile time, which is minimal. I'll add it as a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the notion of good practices with regular expressions<sup>*</sup>. An useless capturing group wastes memory for nothing and don't make your pattern more readable. Use it only if you need it.

About the performances between a capturing group and a non capturing group: You can have an huge difference depending of the regex engine you use. To give an idea, a non-capturing group can be 150x faster than a capture group in PHP.

<sup>*</sup> *A regular expression is build to be the most efficient as possible. It only depends  of what you are trying to do and which engine you are using. The building of a pattern depends of the regex engine mechanisms. With this context, it is not very relevant to try to apply "good practices". However, with the experience, you will apply well-know recipes for some kind of situations.*

Comment: `a non-capturing group can be 150x faster than a capture group in PHP.` Any source for this? And does it include the time to do substring operation?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to refer to the group (the real purpose of a capturing group is to be able to refer to it in a replacement or rewrite target, for instance) or apply a quantifier to it, the only real difference is in readability.

There is also a tiny performance penalty because the regex engine will have to keep the group matches in memory, so if you're worried about such things you can always turn the groups into non-capturing ones with `?:`, i.e. `(?:.*)`, but that does end up adding even more special characters into the regex and making it less readable.

In the end it's partially a question of preference, but in general I haven't seen many (if any) people write redundant capture groups on purpose.